# how can I pick up the dbms_output.put_line output of a procedure in node-oracledb

Tags: node.js, oracle, dbms-output, node-oracledb

Here is an example of what I want to do, the problem is that I do not understand how to collect all the output `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` in the procedure.

There are two ways to do it and I do not know if any is the right one for me.

The example was taken from the following link.

> NAME: dbmsoutput.js
>
> DESCRIPTION:
>              Shows two methods of displaying PL/SQL DBMS_OUTPUT in node-oracledb.
>               The second method depends on these PL/SQL objects:
>                 create or replace type dorow as table of varchar2(32767);
>   https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/using-dbmsoutput-with-nodejs-and-node-oracledb

```
        'use strict';
        var async = require('async');
        var oracledb = require('oracledb');
        var dbconfig = require('./dbconfig.js');
        oracledb.createPool(
          dbconfig,
            function(err, pool) {
                if (err)
                console.error(err.message)
                else
                doit(pool);
            });
            var doit = function(pool) {
            async.waterfall(
            [
              function(cb) {
                pool.getConnection(cb);
              },
              // Tell the DB to buffer DBMS_OUTPUT
              enableDbmsOutput,
              // Method 1: Fetch a line of DBMS_OUTPUT at a time
              createDbmsOutput,
              fetchDbmsOutputLine,
              // Method 2: Use a pipelined query to get DBMS_OUTPUT 
              //createDbmsOutput,
              function(conn, cb) {
                executeSql(
                  conn,
                  "begin NoticiasMasVistas(2018); end;", [], { resultSet: true}, cb);
              },
              printQueryResults
            ],
            function (err, conn) {
            if (err) { console.error("In waterfall error cb: ==>", err, "<=="); }
            conn.release(
                function (err) { 
                    if (err) console.error(err.message);
                    let pool = oracledb.getPool();
                    pool.close(10);
                });
            }
          )
        };
        var enableDbmsOutput = function (conn, cb) {
          conn.execute(
            "begin dbms_output.enable(null); end;",
            function(err) { return cb(err, conn) });
        }
        var createDbmsOutput = function (conn, cb) {
          conn.execute(
            `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NoticiasMasVistas(p_anio NUMBER) IS 
                v_IdPer ej_periodico.IdPer%TYPE;
                v_numNoticias INTEGER;
              CURSOR cPeriodico IS
                SELECT p.Nombre, p.IdPer FROM ej_periodico p;

              CURSOR cNoticiasMes IS
                SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM n.FechaPub) mes, n.Titular, n.NumVisitas
                  FROM ej_noticia n 
                  WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM n.FechaPub) = p_anio
                  AND n.IdPer = v_IdPer
                  AND n.NumVisitas = (SELECT MAX(n2.NumVisitas) 
                    FROM ej_noticia n2
                    WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM n2.FechaPub) = p_anio
                    AND n2.IdPer = n.IdPer
                    AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM n2.FechaPub) =  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM n.FechaPub));
              BEGIN
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NOTICIAS MAS VISITADAS ' || p_anio);
              FOR rPeriodico IN cPeriodico LOOP
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Perdiodico : ' || rPeriodico.Nombre);
                v_IdPer := rPeriodico.IdPer;
                v_numNoticias := 0;
                FOR rNoticiasMes IN cNoticiasMes LOOP
                  v_numNoticias := v_numNoticias + 1;
                  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  Mes: ' || TO_CHAR(rNoticiasMes.mes,'99') ||
                    ': ' || RPAD(rNoticiasMes.Titular,70));
                  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('            ' || rNoticiasMes.numVisitas || ' Visitas.');
                END LOOP;
                  IF v_numNoticias = 0 THEN
                  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  No se han publicado noticias durante 2018');
                  END IF;
              END LOOP;
            END;`,
            function(err) { return cb(err, conn) });
        }
        var fetchDbmsOutputLine = function (conn, cb) {
          conn.execute(
            "begin NoticiasMasVistas(2018); end;",
            {},
            function(err, result) {
              if (err) {
                return cb(err, conn);
              } else if (result.outBinds.st == 1) {
                return cb(null, conn);  // no more output
              } else {
                console.log(result.outBinds.ln);
                return fetchDbmsOutputLine(conn, cb);
              }
            });
          }
        var executeSql = function (conn, sql, binds, options, cb) {
          conn.execute(
            sql, binds, options,
            function (err, result) {
              if (err)
                cb(err, conn)
              else
                cb(null, conn, result);
            });
        }
        var printQueryResults = function(conn, result, cb) {
          if (result.resultSet) {
            fetchOneRowFromRS(conn, result.resultSet, cb);
          } else if (result.rows && result.rows.length > 0) {
            console.log(result.rows);
            return cb(null, conn);
          } else {
            console.log("No results");
            return cb(null, conn);
          }
        }
        function fetchOneRowFromRS(conn, resultSet, cb) {
          resultSet.getRow(  // note: getRows would be more efficient
            function (err, row) {
              if (err) {
                cb(err, conn);
              } else if (row) {
                console.log(row);
                fetchOneRowFromRS(conn, resultSet, cb);
              } else {
                cb(null, conn);
              }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Why do you want to get results from `dbms_output` in the first place?  That package is used for things like very basic debugging and writing data for command line scripts.  It is not a normal method of returning data to a calling program.  Unless you are doing something like writing an IDE to develop stored procedures or writing an app to replace `SQL*Plus`, I can't think of too many good reasons to want an application to read data from `dbms_output`.

Comment: The example you link to has something you're missing: calls to dbms_output.get_line or dbms_output.get_lines. These are needed to read data from the output buffer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two runnable examples in the node-oracledb repo:

- [dbmsoutputgetline.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/dbmsoutputgetline.js)
- [dbmsoutputpipe.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/dbmsoutputpipe.js)

The first one calls DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE() for each line of output so it is likely to be slower than the pipe example, however it is simpler so it may be handy for quick tests or where the number of output lines is small.  The pipe example can make use of optimized query code to fetch multiple records at a time from the database.

Since they were written (and the blog post created), node-oracledb code has been [improved](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/node-oracledb-v2-query-methods-and-fetch-tuning) and you may find that doing a direct fetch, or even calling getRow() singular is fast enough, so the pipe example could be simplified, if that is an issue for you.

I would also recommend using the async/await style of programming now, since that is often easier to get right.